# Is there a version of 'inapproducts.list' that can be called from my app on the phone?

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

The Google Play Store back end has a call to retrieve all products for an app.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/list

Is there a way to do this from my Kotlin client on the phone using BillingClient or something similar?